# Grails 2.4.5 dependency resolution errors

Tags: java, grails

This is probably something simple. I'm a grails newb trying to upgrade an old grails test tool. Commands I'm running are:

```
grails stop-app;grails clean
```

But based on the errors I'm seeing, I expect I'll be seeing these elsewhere also. Errors I'm seeing are:

```
| Loading Grails 2.4.5
| Warning grailsRepo() method deprecated. Legacy Grails SVN repositories are not supported by Aether.
| Configuring classpath
| Error Resolve error obtaining dependencies: Could not transfer artifact org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:4.0.9.RELEASE from/to grailsCentral (https://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
| Error Resolve error obtaining dependencies: Could not transfer artifact org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:4.0.9.RELEASE from/to grailsCentral (https://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
| Error Could not transfer artifact org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:4.0.9.RELEASE from/to grailsCentral (https://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
| Run 'grails dependency-report' for further information.
```

BuildConfig.groovy I'm using is here:

```
grails.servlet.version = "2.5" // Change depending on target container compliance (2.5 or 3.0)
grails.project.class.dir = "target/classes"
grails.project.test.class.dir = "target/test-classes"
grails.project.test.reports.dir = "target/test-reports"
grails.project.target.level = 1.8
grails.project.source.level = 1.8
grails.project.war.file = "target/war/${appName}.war"
grails.server.port.http=8027
grails.project.dependency.resolver = "maven"

grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
    // inherit Grails' default dependencies
    inherits("global") {
        // specify dependency exclusions here; for example, uncomment this to disable ehcache:
        // excludes 'ehcache'
    }
    log "verbose" // log level of Ivy resolver, either 'error', 'warn', 'info', 'debug' or 'verbose'
    checksums true // Whether to verify checksums on resolve

        repositories {
        inherits true // Whether to inherit repository definitions from plugins

        grailsPlugins()
        grailsHome()
        grailsCentral()

        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()

        // uncomment these (or add new ones) to enable remote dependency resolution from public Maven repositories
         mavenRepo  "https://repo01.dev.redactedmedia.net/artifactory/libs-snapshot"
         mavenRepo  "https://repo01.dev.redactedmedia.net/artifactory/libs-release"
//          mavenRepo  "https://repo01.dev.redactedmedia.net/artifactory/ext-release-local"

          mavenRepo  "http://jcenter.bintray.com/joda-time/"
          mavenRepo "https://repository.cloudera.com/artifactory/repo/org/javolution/javolution-core-java/6.0.0/"
            mavenRepo "http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/"
            mavenRepo "http://download.java.net/maven/2/"
            mavenRepo "http://repository.jboss.com/maven2/"
            mavenRepo "http://repo.spring.io/milestone/"
          grailsRepo "https://grails.org/plugins"
        //mavenRepo "http://snapshots.repository.codehaus.org"
        //mavenRepo "http://repository.codehaus.org"
        //mavenRepo "http://download.java.net/maven/2/"
        //mavenRepo "http://repository.jboss.com/maven2/"
    }
    dependencies { // specify dependencies here under either 'build', 'compile', 'runtime', 'test' or 'provided' scopes eg.
        runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.20' 
        runtime 'joda-time:joda-time:1.6'
        runtime ('org.xyzpdq:knowledge-api:5.6.0.Final'){transitive = false}
        runtime ('org.xyzpdq:knowledge-internal-api:5.6.0.Final'){transitive = false}
        runtime ('org.xyzpdq:xyzpdq-ant:5.6.0.Final'){transitive = false}
        runtime ('org.xyzpdq:xyzpdq-compiler:5.6.0.Final'){transitive = false}
        runtime ('org.xyzpdq:xyzpdq-core:5.6.0.Final'){transitive = false}
        runtime ('org.xyzpdq:xyzpdq-tables:5.6.0.Final'){transitive = false}
        runtime ('org.xyzpdq:xyzpdq-grid-impl:5.6.0.Final'){transitive = false}
        runtime ('org.xyzpdq:xyzpdq-templates:5.6.0.Final'){transitive = false}
        runtime ('org.mvel:mvel2:2.1.8.Final'){transitive = false}
        runtime ('commons-collections:commons-collections:3.2'){transitive = false}
        runtime ('com.pnw:pnw-fcommons:7.0.0-SNAPSHOT'){transitive = false}
        runtime ('com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:2.2.6'){transitive = false}
        runtime ('com.google.collections:google-collections:1.0'){transitive = false}

        compile ('com.pnw:pnw-thingamajig:7.0.0-SNAPSHOT'){transitive = false}
        compile ('com.pnw:pnw-mysterychickencontracts:7.0.0-SNAPSHOT'){transitive = false}
        compile ('com.pnw:pnw-userdata:7.0.0-SNAPSHOT'){transitive = false}
        compile ('com.pnw:pnw-rulesutils:7.0.0-SNAPSHOT'){transitive = false}
        compile ('com.pnw:pnw-sterlingengine:7.0.0-SNAPSHOT'){transitive = false}
        compile ('com.pnw:pnw-sterlingengine-schema:7.0.0-SNAPSHOT'){transitive = false}
        compile ('com.pnw:pnw-domain:7.0.0-SNAPSHOT'){transitive = false}
        compile ('com.pnw:pnw-sterlingenginecontent:7.0.0-SNAPSHOT'){transitive = false}
        compile ('com.pnw:pnw-data:7.0.0-SNAPSHOT'){transitive = false}
        compile ('org.easymock:easymock:3.1'){transitive = false}

        compile ('com.pnw:pnw-utilities:7.0.0.0'){transitive = false}
        compile ('org.javolution:javolution-core-java:6.2.0rc3'){transitive = true}
        compile ('com.eaio.stringsearch:stringsearch:2'){transitive = false}
        }

    plugins {
        runtime ':hibernate4:4.3.5.2' // or ':hibernate:3.6.10.14'
        runtime ':jquery:1.11.0.2'
        runtime ':resources:1.2.14'

        // Uncomment these (or add new ones) to enable additional resources capabilities
        //runtime ":zipped-resources:1.0"
        //runtime ":cached-resources:1.0"
        //runtime ":yui-minify-resources:0.1.4"

        build ':tomcat:7.0.52.1'

        runtime ':database-migration:1.4.0'

        compile ':cache:1.1.3'

        //compile ':scaffolding:2.0.1' // use latest version here
    }


}
```

OK, this is a dependency tree dump as requested. It's been redacted of course. so if the *pnw* dependencies don't match, thats why.

```
|Loading Grails 2.4.5
Warning |
grailsRepo() method deprecated. Legacy Grails SVN repositories are not supported by Aether.
|Configuring classpath
.
|Environment set to development
.
build - Dependencies for the build system only (total: 33)
+--- xalan:serializer:2.7.2
+--- org.grails:grails-bootstrap:2.4.5
|    \--- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:1.7.5
|    \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.5
|    \--- jline:jline:2.12
|    \--- org.apache.ant:ant:1.8.4
|    \--- org.apache.ant:ant-launcher:1.8.4
|    \--- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.3.11
|    \--- org.apache.ant:ant-trax:1.7.1
|    \--- org.apache.ant:ant-junit:1.8.4
|    \--- net.java.dev.jna:jna:4.0.0
|    \--- org.codehaus.gant:gant_groovy1.8:1.9.6
|    \--- org.apache.ivy:ivy:2.3.0
|    \--- org.fusesource.jansi:jansi:1.11
+--- org.grails:grails-project-api:2.4.5
+--- org.grails:grails-scripts:2.4.5
+--- org.grails:grails-docs:2.4.5
|    \--- org.xhtmlrenderer:core-renderer:R8
|    \--- org.yaml:snakeyaml:1.8
|    \--- org.grails:grails-gdoc-engine:1.0.1
|    \--- org.jsoup:jsoup:1.7.3
|    \--- com.lowagie:itext:2.0.8
|         \--- bouncycastle:bcmail-jdk14:138
|         \--- bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk14:138
|    \--- commons-lang:commons-lang:2.6
+--- org.grails.plugins:tomcat:7.0.52.1
|    \--- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-catalina-ant:7.0.52
|    \--- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-jasper:7.0.52
|         \--- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:7.0.52
|    \--- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-logging-log4j:7.0.52
|    \--- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket:7.0.52
|    \--- org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler:ecj:3.7.2
|    \--- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:7.0.52


provided - Dependencies needed at development time, but not during deployment (total: 1)
+--- javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:3.0.1


compile - Dependencies placed on the classpath for compilation (total: 82)
+--- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.3.11
+--- org.grails:grails-plugin-rest:2.4.5
|    \--- org.grails:grails-plugin-controllers:2.4.5
|         \--- org.grails:grails-async:2.4.5
|              \--- org.codehaus.gpars:gpars:1.2.1
|                   \--- org.codehaus.jsr166-mirror:jsr166y:1.7.0
|         \--- org.grails:grails-plugin-validation:2.4.5
|    \--- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:1.7.5
|    \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.5
|    \--- com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4
|    \--- org.grails:grails-plugin-datasource:2.4.5
|         \--- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:4.0.9.RELEASE
|         \--- org.springframework:spring-context:4.0.9.RELEASE
|              \--- org.springframework:spring-aop:4.0.9.RELEASE
|              \--- org.springframework:spring-expression:4.0.9.RELEASE
|         \--- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-jdbc:7.0.50
|              \--- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-juli:7.0.50
|    \--- org.grails:grails-web:2.4.5
|         \--- org.grails:grails-web-jsp:2.4.5
|         \--- org.grails:grails-web-sitemesh:2.4.5
|              \--- opensymphony:sitemesh:2.4
|         \--- org.grails:grails-web-fileupload:2.4.5
|              \--- commons-fileupload:commons-fileupload:1.3.1
|                   \--- commons-io:commons-io:2.2
|         \--- org.grails:grails-web-gsp:2.4.5
|         \--- org.grails:grails-web-url-mappings:2.4.5
|         \--- org.grails:grails-web-common:2.4.5
|              \--- org.springframework:spring-context-support:4.0.9.RELEASE
|              \--- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:4.0.9.RELEASE
|              \--- org.grails:grails-databinding:2.4.5
|         \--- org.grails:grails-web-databinding:2.4.5
|         \--- org.grails:grails-web-mvc:2.4.5
+--- org.grails:grails-plugin-databinding:2.4.5
|    \--- org.grails:grails-core:2.4.5
|         \--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.0.9.RELEASE
|         \--- org.grails:grails-spring:2.4.5
|         \--- org.grails:grails-bootstrap:2.4.5
|         \--- aopalliance:aopalliance:1.0
|         \--- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:1.0.0.Final
|         \--- org.springframework:spring-beans:4.0.9.RELEASE
+--- org.grails:grails-plugin-i18n:2.4.5
|    \--- commons-lang:commons-lang:2.6
+--- org.grails:grails-plugin-filters:2.4.5
+--- org.grails:grails-plugin-gsp:2.4.5
|    \--- org.grails:grails-web-gsp-taglib:2.4.5
|    \--- org.grails:grails-logging:2.4.5
|    \--- org.grails:grails-plugin-codecs:2.4.5
|         \--- commons-codec:commons-codec:1.6
|         \--- org.grails:grails-encoder:2.4.5
|              \--- org.springframework:spring-web:4.0.9.RELEASE
+--- org.grails:grails-plugin-log4j:2.4.5
|    \--- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:1.7.5
+--- org.grails:grails-plugin-services:2.4.5
|    \--- org.springframework:spring-tx:4.0.9.RELEASE
+--- org.grails:grails-plugin-servlets:2.4.5
+--- org.grails:grails-plugin-url-mappings:2.4.5
|    \--- com.googlecode.concurrentlinkedhashmap:concurrentlinkedhashmap-lru:1.4
|    \--- org.grails:grails-validation:2.4.5
|         \--- commons-validator:commons-validator:1.4.0
+--- com.pnw:pnw-jailoringfuels:7.0.0-SNAPSHOT
+--- com.pnw:pnw-fuelsdocuments:7.0.0-SNAPSHOT
+--- com.pnw:pnw-userdatacalculator:7.0.0-SNAPSHOT
+--- com.pnw:pnw-fuelsutils:7.0.0-SNAPSHOT
+--- com.pnw:pnw-confusionengine:7.0.0-SNAPSHOT
+--- com.pnw:pnw-confusionengine-schema:7.0.0-SNAPSHOT
+--- com.pnw:pnw-domain:7.0.0-SNAPSHOT
+--- com.pnw:pnw-confusionenginecontent:7.0.0-SNAPSHOT
+--- com.pnw:pnw-wierdodata:7.0.0-SNAPSHOT
+--- org.easymock:easymock:3.1
+--- com.pnw:pnw-utilities:7.0.0.0
+--- org.javolution:javolution-core-java:6.2.0rc3
+--- com.eaio.stringsearch:stringsearch:2
+--- org.grails.plugins:cache:1.1.3
|    \--- org.grails.plugins:webxml:1.4.1


runtime - Dependencies needed at runtime but not for compilation (total: 127)
+--- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.3.11
+--- org.grails:grails-plugin-rest:2.4.5
|    \--- org.grails:grails-plugin-controllers:2.4.5
|         \--- org.grails:grails-async:2.4.5
|              \--- org.codehaus.gpars:gpars:1.2.1
|                   \--- org.codehaus.jsr166-mirror:jsr166y:1.7.0
|         \--- org.grails:grails-plugin-validation:2.4.5
|    \--- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:1.7.5
|    \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.5
|    \--- com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4
|    \--- org.grails:grails-plugin-datasource:2.4.5
|         \--- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:4.0.9.RELEASE
|         \--- org.springframework:spring-context:4.0.9.RELEASE
|              \--- org.springframework:spring-aop:4.0.9.RELEASE
|              \--- org.springframework:spring-expression:4.0.9.RELEASE
|         \--- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-logging-log4j:7.0.50
|         \--- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-jdbc:7.0.50
|              \--- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-juli:7.0.50
|    \--- org.grails:grails-web:2.4.5
|         \--- org.grails:grails-web-jsp:2.4.5
|         \--- org.grails:grails-web-sitemesh:2.4.5
|              \--- opensymphony:sitemesh:2.4
|         \--- org.grails:grails-web-fileupload:2.4.5
|              \--- commons-fileupload:commons-fileupload:1.3.1
|                   \--- commons-io:commons-io:2.2
|         \--- org.grails:grails-web-gsp:2.4.5
|         \--- org.springframework:spring-aspects:4.0.9.RELEASE
|         \--- org.grails:grails-web-url-mappings:2.4.5
|         \--- org.grails:grails-web-common:2.4.5
|              \--- org.springframework:spring-context-support:4.0.9.RELEASE
|              \--- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:4.0.9.RELEASE
|              \--- org.grails:grails-databinding:2.4.5
|         \--- org.grails:grails-web-databinding:2.4.5
|         \--- org.aspectj:aspectjrt:1.8.4
|         \--- org.grails:grails-web-mvc:2.4.5
|         \--- org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:1.8.4
+--- org.grails:grails-plugin-databinding:2.4.5
|    \--- org.grails:grails-core:2.4.5
|         \--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.0.9.RELEASE
|         \--- xalan:serializer:2.7.2
|         \--- org.grails:grails-spring:2.4.5
|         \--- org.grails:grails-bootstrap:2.4.5
|         \--- aopalliance:aopalliance:1.0
|         \--- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:1.0.0.Final
|         \--- org.springframework:spring-beans:4.0.9.RELEASE
+--- org.grails:grails-plugin-i18n:2.4.5
|    \--- commons-lang:commons-lang:2.6
+--- org.grails:grails-plugin-filters:2.4.5
+--- org.grails:grails-plugin-gsp:2.4.5
|    \--- org.grails:grails-web-gsp-taglib:2.4.5
|    \--- org.grails:grails-logging:2.4.5
|    \--- org.grails:grails-plugin-codecs:2.4.5
|         \--- commons-codec:commons-codec:1.6
|         \--- org.grails:grails-encoder:2.4.5
|              \--- org.springframework:spring-web:4.0.9.RELEASE
+--- org.grails:grails-plugin-log4j:2.4.5
|    \--- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:1.7.5
+--- org.grails:grails-plugin-services:2.4.5
|    \--- org.springframework:spring-tx:4.0.9.RELEASE
+--- org.grails:grails-plugin-servlets:2.4.5
+--- org.grails:grails-plugin-url-mappings:2.4.5
|    \--- com.googlecode.concurrentlinkedhashmap:concurrentlinkedhashmap-lru:1.4
|    \--- org.grails:grails-validation:2.4.5
|         \--- commons-validator:commons-validator:1.4.0
+--- com.h2database:h2:1.3.176
+--- log4j:log4j:1.2.17
+--- org.grails:grails-resources:2.4.5
+--- mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.20
+--- joda-time:joda-time:1.6
+--- org.pools:knowledge-api:5.6.0.Final
+--- org.pools:knowledge-internal-api:5.6.0.Final
+--- org.pools:drools-ant:5.6.0.Final
+--- org.pools:drools-compiler:5.6.0.Final
+--- org.pools:drools-core:5.6.0.Final
+--- org.pools:drools-decisiontables:5.6.0.Final
+--- org.pools:drools-grid-impl:5.6.0.Final
+--- org.pools:drools-templates:5.6.0.Final
+--- org.mvel:mvel2:2.1.8.Final
+--- commons-collections:commons-collections:3.2
+--- com.pnw:pnw-confusionenginecommons:7.0.0-SNAPSHOT
+--- com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:2.2.6
+--- com.google.collections:google-collections:1.0
+--- com.pnw:pnw-jailoringfuels:7.0.0-SNAPSHOT
+--- com.pnw:pnw-fuelsdocuments:7.0.0-SNAPSHOT
+--- com.pnw:pnw-userdatacalculator:7.0.0-SNAPSHOT
+--- com.pnw:pnw-fuelsutils:7.0.0-SNAPSHOT
+--- com.pnw:pnw-confusionengine:7.0.0-SNAPSHOT
+--- com.pnw:pnw-confusionengine-schema:7.0.0-SNAPSHOT
+--- com.pnw:pnw-domain:7.0.0-SNAPSHOT
+--- com.pnw:pnw-confusionenginecontent:7.0.0-SNAPSHOT
+--- com.pnw:pnw-wierdodata:7.0.0-SNAPSHOT
+--- org.easymock:easymock:3.1
+--- com.pnw:pnw-utilities:7.0.0.0
+--- org.javolution:javolution-core-java:6.2.0rc3
+--- com.eaio.stringsearch:stringsearch:2
+--- org.grails.plugins:hibernate4:4.3.5.2
|    \--- org.hibernate:hibernate-ehcache:4.3.5.Final
|         \--- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging-annotations:1.2.0.Beta1
|         \--- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:4.3.5.Final
|              \--- org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction:jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec:1.0.0.Final
|              \--- antlr:antlr:2.7.7
|              \--- org.jboss:jandex:1.1.0.Final
|    \--- org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:5.0.3.Final
|         \--- com.fasterxml:classmate:1.0.0
|    \--- net.sf.ehcache:ehcache-core:2.4.8
|    \--- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:3.1.0.GA
|    \--- org.grails:grails-datastore-core:3.1.0.RELEASE
|         \--- org.javassist:javassist:3.17.1-GA
|         \--- javax.transaction:jta:1.1
|    \--- org.grails:grails-datastore-gorm:3.1.0.RELEASE
|    \--- org.grails:grails-datastore-gorm-hibernate4:3.1.0.RELEASE
|         \--- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:4.0.4.Final
|         \--- org.grails:grails-datastore-gorm-hibernate-core:3.1.0.RELEASE
|              \--- org.grails:grails-datastore-gorm-plugin-support:3.1.0.RELEASE
|              \--- org.springframework:spring-orm:4.0.9.RELEASE
|         \--- dom4j:dom4j:1.6.1
|    \--- org.grails:grails-datastore-simple:3.1.0.RELEASE
|    \--- javax.validation:validation-api:1.1.0.Final
+--- org.grails.plugins:jquery:1.11.0.2
+--- org.grails.plugins:resources:1.2.14
+--- org.grails.plugins:database-migration:1.4.0
|    \--- org.liquibase:liquibase-core:2.0.5
+--- org.grails.plugins:cache:1.1.3
|    \--- org.grails.plugins:webxml:1.4.1


test - Dependencies needed for test compilation and execution but not at runtime (total: 144)
+--- javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:3.0.1
+--- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.3.11
+--- org.grails:grails-plugin-rest:2.4.5
|    \--- org.grails:grails-plugin-controllers:2.4.5
|         \--- org.grails:grails-async:2.4.5
|              \--- org.codehaus.gpars:gpars:1.2.1
|                   \--- org.codehaus.jsr166-mirror:jsr166y:1.7.0
|         \--- org.grails:grails-plugin-validation:2.4.5
|    \--- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:1.7.5
|    \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.5
|    \--- com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4
|    \--- org.grails:grails-plugin-datasource:2.4.5
|         \--- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:4.0.9.RELEASE
|         \--- org.springframework:spring-context:4.0.9.RELEASE
|              \--- org.springframework:spring-aop:4.0.9.RELEASE
|              \--- org.springframework:spring-expression:4.0.9.RELEASE
|         \--- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-logging-log4j:7.0.50
|         \--- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-jdbc:7.0.50
|              \--- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-juli:7.0.50
|    \--- org.grails:grails-web:2.4.5
|         \--- org.grails:grails-web-jsp:2.4.5
|         \--- org.grails:grails-web-sitemesh:2.4.5
|              \--- opensymphony:sitemesh:2.4
|         \--- org.grails:grails-web-fileupload:2.4.5
|              \--- commons-fileupload:commons-fileupload:1.3.1
|                   \--- commons-io:commons-io:2.2
|         \--- org.grails:grails-web-gsp:2.4.5
|         \--- org.springframework:spring-aspects:4.0.9.RELEASE
|         \--- org.grails:grails-web-url-mappings:2.4.5
|         \--- org.grails:grails-web-common:2.4.5
|              \--- org.springframework:spring-context-support:4.0.9.RELEASE
|              \--- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:4.0.9.RELEASE
|              \--- org.grails:grails-databinding:2.4.5
|         \--- org.grails:grails-web-databinding:2.4.5
|         \--- org.aspectj:aspectjrt:1.8.4
|         \--- org.grails:grails-web-mvc:2.4.5
|         \--- org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:1.8.4
+--- org.grails:grails-plugin-databinding:2.4.5
|    \--- org.grails:grails-core:2.4.5
|         \--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.0.9.RELEASE
|         \--- xalan:serializer:2.7.2
|         \--- org.grails:grails-spring:2.4.5
|         \--- org.grails:grails-bootstrap:2.4.5
|         \--- aopalliance:aopalliance:1.0
|         \--- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:1.0.0.Final
|         \--- org.springframework:spring-beans:4.0.9.RELEASE
+--- org.grails:grails-plugin-i18n:2.4.5
|    \--- commons-lang:commons-lang:2.6
+--- org.grails:grails-plugin-filters:2.4.5
+--- org.grails:grails-plugin-gsp:2.4.5
|    \--- org.grails:grails-web-gsp-taglib:2.4.5
|    \--- org.grails:grails-logging:2.4.5
|    \--- org.grails:grails-plugin-codecs:2.4.5
|         \--- commons-codec:commons-codec:1.6
|         \--- org.grails:grails-encoder:2.4.5
|              \--- org.springframework:spring-web:4.0.9.RELEASE
+--- org.grails:grails-plugin-log4j:2.4.5
|    \--- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:1.7.5
+--- org.grails:grails-plugin-services:2.4.5
|    \--- org.springframework:spring-tx:4.0.9.RELEASE
+--- org.grails:grails-plugin-servlets:2.4.5
+--- org.grails:grails-plugin-url-mappings:2.4.5
|    \--- com.googlecode.concurrentlinkedhashmap:concurrentlinkedhashmap-lru:1.4
|    \--- org.grails:grails-validation:2.4.5
|         \--- commons-validator:commons-validator:1.4.0
+--- org.grails:grails-plugin-testing:2.4.5
|    \--- org.grails:grails-plugin-domain-class:2.4.5
|    \--- org.grails:grails-test:2.4.5
|         \--- org.grails:grails-project-api:2.4.5
|              \--- org.apache.ant:ant:1.8.4
|                   \--- org.apache.ant:ant-launcher:1.8.4
|              \--- jline:jline:2.12
|              \--- org.codehaus.gant:gant_groovy1.8:1.9.6
|              \--- org.fusesource.jansi:jansi:1.11
|         \--- org.objenesis:objenesis:1.4
|    \--- org.grails:grails-plugin-converters:2.4.5
|    \--- org.grails:grails-plugin-mimetypes:2.4.5
|    \--- cglib:cglib:2.2.2
|         \--- asm:asm:3.3.1
|    \--- org.springframework:spring-test:4.0.9.RELEASE
+--- org.spockframework:spock-core:0.7-groovy-2.0
|    \--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.3
+--- cglib:cglib-nodep:2.2.2
+--- junit:junit:4.11
+--- com.h2database:h2:1.3.176
+--- log4j:log4j:1.2.17
+--- org.grails:grails-resources:2.4.5
+--- mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.20
+--- joda-time:joda-time:1.6
+--- org.pools:knowledge-api:5.6.0.Final
+--- org.pools:knowledge-internal-api:5.6.0.Final
+--- org.pools:drools-ant:5.6.0.Final
+--- org.pools:drools-compiler:5.6.0.Final
+--- org.pools:drools-core:5.6.0.Final
+--- org.pools:drools-decisiontables:5.6.0.Final
+--- org.pools:drools-grid-impl:5.6.0.Final
+--- org.pools:drools-templates:5.6.0.Final
+--- org.mvel:mvel2:2.1.8.Final
+--- commons-collections:commons-collections:3.2
+--- com.pnw:pnw-confusionenginecommons:7.0.0-SNAPSHOT
+--- com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:2.2.6
+--- com.google.collections:google-collections:1.0
+--- com.pnw:pnw-jailoringfuels:7.0.0-SNAPSHOT
+--- com.pnw:pnw-fuelsdocuments:7.0.0-SNAPSHOT
+--- com.pnw:pnw-userdatacalculator:7.0.0-SNAPSHOT
+--- com.pnw:pnw-fuelsutils:7.0.0-SNAPSHOT
+--- com.pnw:pnw-confusionengine:7.0.0-SNAPSHOT
+--- com.pnw:pnw-confusionengine-schema:7.0.0-SNAPSHOT
+--- com.pnw:pnw-domain:7.0.0-SNAPSHOT
+--- com.pnw:pnw-confusionenginecontent:7.0.0-SNAPSHOT
+--- com.pnw:pnw-wierdoantdata:7.0.0-SNAPSHOT
+--- org.easymock:easymock:3.1
+--- com.pnw:pnw-utilities:7.0.0.0
+--- org.javolution:javolution-core-java:6.2.0rc3
+--- com.eaio.stringsearch:stringsearch:2
+--- org.grails.plugins:hibernate4:4.3.5.2
|    \--- org.hibernate:hibernate-ehcache:4.3.5.Final
|         \--- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging-annotations:1.2.0.Beta1
|         \--- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:4.3.5.Final
|              \--- org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction:jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec:1.0.0.Final
|              \--- antlr:antlr:2.7.7
|              \--- org.jboss:jandex:1.1.0.Final
|    \--- org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:5.0.3.Final
|         \--- com.fasterxml:classmate:1.0.0
|    \--- net.sf.ehcache:ehcache-core:2.4.8
|    \--- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:3.1.0.GA
|    \--- org.grails:grails-datastore-core:3.1.0.RELEASE
|         \--- org.javassist:javassist:3.17.1-GA
|         \--- javax.transaction:jta:1.1
|    \--- org.grails:grails-datastore-gorm:3.1.0.RELEASE
|    \--- org.grails:grails-datastore-gorm-hibernate4:3.1.0.RELEASE
|         \--- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:4.0.4.Final
|         \--- org.grails:grails-datastore-gorm-hibernate-core:3.1.0.RELEASE
|              \--- org.grails:grails-datastore-gorm-plugin-support:3.1.0.RELEASE
|              \--- org.springframework:spring-orm:4.0.9.RELEASE
|         \--- dom4j:dom4j:1.6.1
|    \--- org.grails:grails-datastore-simple:3.1.0.RELEASE
|    \--- javax.validation:validation-api:1.1.0.Final
+--- org.grails.plugins:jquery:1.11.0.2
+--- org.grails.plugins:resources:1.2.14
+--- org.grails.plugins:database-migration:1.4.0
|    \--- org.liquibase:liquibase-core:2.0.5
+--- org.grails.plugins:cache:1.1.3
|    \--- org.grails.plugins:webxml:1.4.1
```

Comment: What is a result of `| Run 'grails dependency-report' for further information.`?

Comment: Wow. I'll do it but it's going to be hard. Some of the items likely won't map but if they don't it's due to redaction of proprietary info. Those aren't the things I'm having issues with anyway.

Comment: Doh!! I just spotted something. Apparenlty not fully upgraded yet from 2.3.9

Comment: Woohoo!! That seems to have helped. I searched high and low and got rid of every reference to 2.3.9, redid some parts of my environment and now all I have left is the repo warning about grailsRepo() being deprecated. Any ideas what that is about? I've already tried the answer below.

Comment: I've found that changing the line with grailsRepo on it to mavenRepo makes the error go away. This makes sense since my searches were turning up the method that prints the error which is the API method. Sure would have been nice if someone had done their documentation (javadocs) though, then I would have known right away. As it stands I don't know anything about why or what I should use instead. mavenRepo is just a guess.

Answer (score 2):

Use this repository first:

```
mavenRepo "http://repo.grails.org/grails/repo"
```